# Prestashop 1.6 and SwiftMailer with PHP version 5.6 - fsockopen error

Tags: php, smtp, ssl-certificate, prestashop-1.6, swiftmailer

I have an issue with sending mail using the version of Swiftmailer that came with PS1.6

Swift Error: The SMTP connection failed to start [ssl://mail.wineofthemonth.co.za:465]: fsockopen returned Error Number 0 and Error String ''

This is due to the fact that since PHP 5.6 the verify_peer option is set to true by default.

Now I have found various instructions on how to set verify peer to false:

```
$https['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$https['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

The issue is that there is no place to set this in the version of Swiftmailer that is being used in Prestashop.

So my question is, where in class/mail.php or anywhere else would I set verify_peer to false?

Here is the line in mail.php that I think pertains to this:

```
$connection = new Swift_Connection_SMTP(
                    $configuration['PS_MAIL_SERVER'],
                    $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_PORT'],
                    $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION'] == 'ssl' ? Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_SSL : (($configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION'] == 'tls' ? Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_TLS : Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_OFF))
                );
```

There is also a sendMailtest method that could lend more clarity:

```
public static function sendMailTest($smtpChecked, $smtpServer, $content, $subject, $type, $to, $from, $smtpLogin, $smtpPassword, $smtpPort = 25, $smtpEncryption)
    {
        $result = false;
        try {
            if ($smtpChecked)
            {
                $smtp = new Swift_Connection_SMTP($smtpServer, $smtpPort, ($smtpEncryption == 'off') ?
                    Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_OFF : (($smtpEncryption == 'tls') ? Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_TLS : Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_SSL));
                $smtp->setUsername($smtpLogin);
                $smtp->setpassword($smtpPassword);
                $smtp->setTimeout(5);
                $swift = new Swift($smtp, Configuration::get('PS_MAIL_DOMAIN'));
            }
            else
                $swift = new Swift(new Swift_Connection_NativeMail(), Configuration::get('PS_MAIL_DOMAIN'));

            $message = new Swift_Message($subject, $content, $type);

            if ($swift->send($message, $to, $from))
                $result = true;

            $swift->disconnect();
        } catch (Swift_ConnectionException $e) {
            $result = $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Swift_Message_MimeException $e) {
            $result = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Alternatively, where in any conf or ini file, could I set verify_peer to false?

Prestashop 1.6.1.1 to 1.6.1.4 are affected.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

1. Open the file `/tools/swift/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php`
2. On line `263`, just before `$this->_stream =`, add these two lines:

   `$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;`

   `$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;`

**The code should now looks like this:**

```
[...]

$options = array();
if (!empty($this->_params['sourceIp'])) {
    $options['socket']['bindto'] = $this->_params['sourceIp'].':0';
}
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
$this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create($options));

[...]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: My file structure does not look like this.  In fact, there is no classes folder and no StreamBuffer.php file anywhere.  This is the version of SwiftMailer that comes with Prestashop 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the version 3.3.2 of Swiftmailer that comes with Prestashop 1.6.1 altogether, and I installed the latest version using composer.
Then I adapted the file `classes/Mail.php` as follows. The diff contains only the modified lines.

```
- include_once(_PS_SWIFT_DIR_.'Swift.php');
- include_once(_PS_SWIFT_DIR_.'Swift/Connection/SMTP.php');
- include_once(_PS_SWIFT_DIR_.'Swift/Connection/NativeMail.php');
- include_once(_PS_SWIFT_DIR_.'Swift/Plugin/Decorator.php');
+ require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

- $to_list = new Swift_RecipientList();
+ $message = new Swift_Message();

- $to_list->addTo($addr, $to_name);
+ $message->addTo($addr, $to_name);
(...) similar three times

- $connection = new Swift_Connection_SMTP(
-     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SERVER'],
-     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_PORT'],
-     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION'] == 'ssl' ? Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_SSL : (($configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION'] == 'tls' ? Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_TLS : Swift_Connection_SMTP::ENC_OFF))
- );
+ $connection = new Swift_SmtpTransport(
+     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SERVER'],
+     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_PORT'],
+     $configuration['PS_MAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION']
+ );

- $connection = new Swift_Connection_NativeMail();
+ $swift = new Swift_Mailer($connection);

- $message = new Swift_Message($subject);
+ $message->setSubject($subject);

- $message->headers->setEncoding('Q');

- $template_vars['{shop_logo}'] = $message->attach(new Swift_Message_EmbeddedFile(new Swift_File($logo), null, ImageManager::getMimeTypeByExtension($logo)));
+ $template_vars['{shop_logo}'] = $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath($logo));

- $swift->attachPlugin(new Swift_Plugin_Decorator(array($to_plugin => $template_vars)), 'decorator');
- if ($configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_BOTH || $configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_TEXT) {
-     $message->attach(new Swift_Message_Part($template_txt, 'text/plain', '8bit', 'utf-8'));
- }
- if ($configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_BOTH || $configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_HTML) {
-     $message->attach(new Swift_Message_Part($template_html, 'text/html', '8bit', 'utf-8'));
- }
+ $swift->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin(array($to_plugin => $template_vars)));
+ if ($configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_BOTH || $configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_TEXT) {
+     $message->addPart($template_txt, 'text/plain', 'utf-8');
+ }
+ if ($configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_BOTH || $configuration['PS_MAIL_TYPE'] == Mail::TYPE_HTML) {
+     $message->addPart($template_html, 'text/html', 'utf-8');
+ }

- $message->attach(new Swift_Message_Attachment($attachment['content'], $attachment['name'], $attachment['mime']));
+ $message->attach(new Swift_Attachment($attachment['content'], $attachment['name'], $attachment['mime']));

- $send = $swift->send($message, $to_list, new Swift_Address($from, $from_name));
- $swift->disconnect();

+ $message->setFrom(array($from => $from_name));
+ $send = $swift->send($message);

- foreach (array_merge($to_list->getTo(), $to_list->getCc(), $to_list->getBcc()) as $recipient) {
-    /** @var Swift_Address $recipient */
-     $mail->id = null;
-     $mail->recipient = substr($recipient->getAddress(), 0, 126);
-     $mail->add();
- }
+ foreach (array_merge($message->getTo() ?: [], $message->getCc() ?: [], $message->getBcc() ?: []) as $recipient_mail => $recipient_name) {
+     $mail->id = null;
+     $mail->recipient = $recipient_mail;
+     $mail->add();
+ }

- public static function sendMailTest($smtpChecked, $smtpServer, $content, $subject, $type, $to, $from, $smtpLogin, $smtpPassword, $smtpPort = 25, $smtpEncryption)
+ public static function sendMailTest($smtpChecked, $smtpServer, $content, $subject, $type, $to, $from, $smtpLogin, $smtpPassword, $smtpPort = 25, $smtpEncryption)
+ {
+     $result = false;
+     try {
+         if ($smtpChecked) {
+             $smtp = new Swift_SmtpTransport($smtpServer, $smtpPort, $smtpEncryption);
+             $smtp->setUsername($smtpLogin);
+             $smtp->setpassword($smtpPassword);
+             $smtp->setTimeout(5);
+             $swift = new Swift_Mailer($smtp);
+         } else {
+             $swift = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_SmtpTransport('localhost', 25));
+         }
+ 
+         $message = new Swift_Message();
+         $message->setFrom($from)->setTo($to)->setSubject($subject)->setBody($content);
+ 
+         if ($swift->send($message)) {
+             $result = true;
+         }
+ 
+     } catch (Swift_SwiftException $e) {
+         $result = $e->getMessage();
+     }
+ 
+     return $result;
+ }

- return vsprintf("<%s.%d.%s@%s>", $midparams);
+ return vsprintf("%s.%d.%s@%s", $midparams);
```